# Android Chomecast Sender App: MediaRouteActionProvider

Tags: android, google-cast

I have a problem with a Chromecast sender app for Android.  This is my second sender app so, generally speaking, I have the basics down.

What is right:

When I run the app directly from Eclipse, it works on both of my test devices.
When I run the app directly from Android Studio, it works on both of my test devices.

The problem:

When I generate a signed APK through BOTH Eclipse and Android Studio, the app crashes when it reaches the “cast activity” on both devices.

The logcat error is as follows:

```
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144): Cannot instantiate class: android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.victuallist.shred-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.victuallist.shred-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v7.internal.view.f.a(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v7.internal.view.f.b(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v7.internal.view.d.a(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v7.internal.view.d.inflate(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at com.victuallist.castgame.CastGameActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v4.app.k.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v7.a.n.a(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v7.a.g.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.support.v7.a.o.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-04 12:39:54.887: W/SupportMenuInflater(31144):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 12:39:54.897: D/AndroidRuntime(31144): Shutting down VM
07-04 12:39:54.897: W/dalvikvm(31144): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41611ba8)
07-04 12:39:54.897: E/AndroidRuntime(31144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

UPDATE:  It seems that I have it working.  I disabled proguard.  Despite having it running, I am still interested in knowing why I encountered the problem.  Any tips would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 3 lines to your proguard file ...

```
-keep        class android.support.v13.** { *; }
-keep        class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep        class android.support.v4.** { *; }
```

will solve class not found issues in all the support libs.

Comment: These lines solved the problem and allowed me to keep proguard active.  Thanks!  And for others, also look at answer given by @CommonsWare

Comment: As I understand it, `-keep` not only prevents the classes from being renamed, but also prevents them from being removed in the shrinking phase. I would recommend using `-keep` on a narrower scope, or switching to `-keepnames` for the wildcards (and, if still needed, `-keep` the `MediaRouteActionProvider`). See: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

Comment: Specifically the constructor is being shrunk out of MediaRouteActionProvider and is being called via reflection. This proguard rule is to keep the constructor `-keepclassmembers public class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider {
   public <init>(...);
}`

Comment: As others have said, putting such broad "keep" statements defeats one of the main purposes of Proguard, which is to strip out unused code to make the app smaller and faster. This answer will "keep" all classes in the support libraries, the majority of which your app will not be using.

Answer (score 6):

ProGuard does not examine things like menu resources to try to find classes that need to be free from obfuscation. Any classes that you reference from resources need to be left untouched, typically by some flavor of a `-keep` directive in your ProGuard configuration.

What probably happened is that ProGuard obfuscated `MediaRouteActionProvider`, so your code compiled, but then Android could not find the class by its un-obfuscated name.

Comment: If I could have accepted two answers as "correct", I would have also selected this one.  Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I was having the same issue when I migrated the project to AndroidX. I added 
-keep class androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider {
    public <methods>;
}

-keep public class androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider {
    public <methods>;
}
. This solved the issue