# Chromecast button not visible in android

Tags: java, android, chromecast

I am following the [code lab tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#4).

My Gradle file looks like this

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'}
```

This is my CastOptionsProvider class

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {
@Override
public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
    return new CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.chromecast_app_id))
            .build();
}

@Override
public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
    return null;
}}
```

This is the menu xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always" /></menu>
```

And this is my OnCreateOptionsMenu method in MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
    mediaRouteMenuItem = CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    return true;
}
```

And this in the manifest file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="com.mypackage.CastOptionsProvider" />
```

I have followed the codelab tutorial to its exact form, copy and pasted everything while changing those variable which needs to be changed.
My application and the chromecast device are connected to the same network. The Chromecast button appears in the Youtube app but not on my app. What am I missing ?
Thanks

Comment: see in your linked tutorial.at last notes

Comment: Remember that you need to repeat these steps to add the Cast button in ALL activities of your project.....This Line is Write at last in your Given Link....You did it in all activities..?

Comment: I have done this in every Activity

Comment: i checked it...nothing problem in your code...Both are same

Comment: i think...now you have to Repeat your all steps again..insted of wasting your time to find out the solution....because there is no problem in your code.

Comment: @theanilpaudel any success in this issue ?

Comment: @SalmanAziz iirc the accepted answer worked for me.

Comment: @theanilpaudel you used 4F8B3483 this app id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be an invalid app_id.

You might try replacing your chromecast_app_id string resource with the app_id string resource value from the sample project.

(Right now, it's 4F8B3483. See: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/res/values/strings.xml).

Believe it or not, switching to that value made the cast icon visible in my app.

Answer (score 3):

If everything is done properly, you just need to restart cast device (it does not work with your app_id without restarting after registration).

Answer (score 3):

Check in [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish/) if your Application ID is correct and status is Published.

When publish your Application ID, restart your Chromecast device.

For testing purposes, you can use CC1AD845 or 4F8B3483 as Application ID. These are from Google sample apps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer as the accepted answer did nothing for me. The issue happened to me only when building a proguarded version of my app.

I had to add a couple lines to my proguard file (essentially all of the classes referenced by xml as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24578823/1048847)

```
-keep class com.your.package.CastOptionsProvider { *; } 
// I have a custom MediaRouteActionProvider but this may need to be 
// android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider in the case of OP
-keep class com.your.package.MediaRouteActionProvider { *; }
```

Answer (score -2):

you are missing attribute icon here

```
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/chromebutton"  app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always" /></menu>
```

Comment: Do we have to provide it explicitly ?